# How can I place an indented list on same line after a word or phrase?

Tags: lists, indentation

I need to approximate a document with the following format where a list starts after a word or phrase on the same line:

```
word or phrase source language       1) First translated definition
                                         - Example phrase with word in source language
                                           Example phrase translation to target

                                         - Another source example
                                           Another target translation

                                     2) Second translated definition
```

I'm totally new to lyx or latex. After fiddling around with lists I think I should be able to figure out how to indent a list and create a nested list. Should I be investigating text boxes, tabs, tables, or columns to achieve this?  Will I have to create my own 'environment' for this format? Or can I find a template that does this?  Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: use a `minipage` with top alignment is one possibility. Putting both columns in a `tabularx` is another possibility

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a bit more information about your typesetting needs. E.g., should page breaks be allowed in the list? If so, might they be allowed anywhere in the list, or only at certain points?

Answer (score 1):

Building on Steven Segletes's comment, I suggest you employ a two-column `tabularx` environment and bespoke `enumerate` and `itemize` environments -- named `myenumerate` and `myitemize`in the code below) in the right-hand column of the tabularx environment.

Two remarks about this setup:

- Line-breaking is allowed in the first-level (enumerated) and second-level (itemized) list environments in the right-hand column.
- Line-breaking is also permissible in the left-hand column. It this is not allowed, simply replace `P{3cm}` with `l`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,enumitem,ragged2e}

% Automatic line breaking and hanging indentation in 1st col.:
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash%
     \hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}p{#1}}

% Define custom enumerated and itemized list environments:
\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenumerate,1]{nosep,wide=0pt,label=\arabic*),
                        before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
                        after =\end{minipage}}
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize,1]{noitemsep,label=-}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} P{3cm} X @{}}
Word or phrase source language &
\begin{myenumerate}
\item First translated definition
  \begin{myitemize}
  \item Example phrase with word in source language

        Example phrase translation in target
  \item Another source example

        Another target translation
  \end{myitemize} 
\item Second translated definition 
  \begin{myitemize}
  \item bla bla bla
  \item ble ble blie
  \end{myitemize}
\end{myenumerate}  \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Really one of a best suggestion...

Comment: @MadyYuvi - Thanks! :-)

Comment: Awesome!  I wasn't expecting to get some working samples!   I have lots to work with now!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an environment `indentation` constructed on the system of lists of LaTeX. The argument of the environment `indentation` is the element of the text on the left. You can put LateX lists in the body of the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}    
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment { indentation } { m }
  { 
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #1 }
    \box_set_dp:Nn \l_tmpa_box \c_zero_dim 
    \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
    \begin { list } 
      { 
        \hspace { \labelsep }
        \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box     
        \hspace { - \labelsep }
      }
      { 
        \dim_set:Nn \leftmargin \l_tmpa_dim
        \dim_set:Nn \itemindent { - \leftmargin }
        \dim_zero:N \labelwidth 
      }
    \item \scan_stop:
  }
  { \end { list } }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}    
\begin{indentation}{word or phrase source }
\begin{itemize}
\item First translated definition
\begin{itemize}
\item Example phrase with word in source language

Example phrase translation to target

\item Another source example

Another target translation
\end{itemize}      
\item Second translated definition 
\end{itemize}
\end{indentation}    
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the previous code]

Comment: Another great example.   These will really help me get up to speed with this!  Thank you!